# Android interstitial only displaying once

Tags: android, admob, native, ads, interstitial

I can only get it to display once, when i request another ad or just try to display the same ad again it does not work..it only displays once no matter what i do. I tried

I have this onCreate

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

  mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId(getString(R.string.interstitial_ad_unit_id));
AdRequest adRequestInterstial =  new AdRequest.Builder()
        .addTestDevice("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")
        .build();
mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequestInterstial);
```

Then i have the summoning code

```
  if(mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()){
                        mInterstitialAd.show();
                       requestNewInterstitial();
                    }
```

And the requestNewInterstitial code:

```
private void requestNewInterstitial() {
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
            .addTestDevice("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")
            .build();

    mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
//listner for adClosed fixed the situation
mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAdClosed() {
        AdRequest adRequest =  new AdRequest.Builder()
                .addTestDevice("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")
                .build();
        mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);
    }
});
```